# Angular Flex Layout - Not working

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I tried to use 2.0.0-beta.9 in my app, a simple test doesn't work

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div>1. One</div> <div>2. Two</div> <div>3. Three</div> <div>4. Four</div>
</div>
```

displays columns instead of rows

I think I am importing the library properly

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {FlexLayoutModule} from "@angular/flex-layout";

import {TestApp} from "./test-app";

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  declarations: [ TestApp ],
  bootstrap: [ TestApp ]
})
export class TestAppModule {

}
```

Comment: It should work...
try to delete node_modules than run npm install and try again.

Comment: try to use angular version 4 which is latest beta is outdated

Comment: you are missing 2 ";"
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

Comment: What was the problem here? The semicolons?

Answer (score 13):

I also got like that problems when I install the lasted `flex-layout` module. The problems is **directive** name changes.
In [website](https://material.angularjs.org), all of the directive are like `layout`, `layout-xs`, `flex` etc...

According to my solution, `directive` name are changed to  `fx + PascalCase`.

Example

```
layout -> fxLayout
flex -> fxFlex
flex-order -> fxFlexOrder
flex-order-gt-md -> fxFlexOrder.gt-md
```

If you check [Layout and Container](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/layout/container), you will see as below image.

[image]

Change above source code to as the following, it is OK for me.

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex>First item in row</div>
    <div fxFlex>Second item in row</div>
</div>
<div fxLayout="column">
    <div fxFlex>First item in column</div>
    <div fxFlex>Second item in column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me!  Not sure why the documentation is  wrong on the angular site. I couldn't get the angular project to compile unless I used

"@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24", in the package.json

Comment: The website you have linked to is for AngularJS Material. For Angular (2+) refer to the [wiki](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki) for **@angular/flex-layout**.

Comment: thank you! Worked for me. Strange that the documentation is wrong

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this issue too and the cause was me using multiple modules and I forgot to import the `FlexLayoutModule` in my "*PagesModule*" modules.

It would work on the main page because it was imported at the top level (*AppModule*) and not on the child modules.

Importing it in the "*PagesModule*" and restarting the development server fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a generic problem, but catches me once in a while:

**Make sure your project is actually compiling!**

If you have an error and the project doesn't compile, then HTML changes won't be shown - which includes directives being added. So if you add a directive to existing code and don't see the change make sure your compile completes.

**Don't get muddled up with the names**

-Use `fxLayout` and not `fxFlexLayout`

-Use `fxLayoutAlign` and not `fxFlexLayoutAlign`